# Is there a standard package that provide latitude/longitude functions in python?

Tags: package-management, python

I'm trying to develop software in python that involves geographic coordinates.
I'd prefer to not rely on custom installed software, and only rely on standard packages.

So far, I've only found [geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/) hosted at Google, which should be useful (it actually provides way more than I need).

Are there any python packages that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python-geopy has been packaged for Ubuntu 12.10. Since 14.04 python3-geopy has been packaged and it's now the current package in the default Ubuntu repositories.

If you can't install the packaged version (e.g. you're using Ubuntu 12.04), the standard way  to install Python packages is to use `pip` (the `python-pip` Ubuntu package). When pip is installed, simply use:

`sudo pip install geopy`

and start using the package!

Note: pip and virtualenv are very useful to be in control of your Python environment, which is not possible with standard Ubuntu packages. You should learn to use them if you want to be serious about your Python development.

Answer (score 0):

I've started using [PyGeodesy](https://pypi.org/project/PyGeodesy/), which is full-featured even if not very pythonic (it's adapted from Javascript).